# How can I make a sub class of NSApplication and use it for running my app?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsapplication

I am trying to make sub class of NSApplication with this code:

```
class MySubNSApplication: NSApplication {
    
    static var internalShared: MySubNSApplication = MySubNSApplication()
    
    static override var shared: MySubNSApplication {
        get {
            return internalShared
        }
        set(newValue) {
            internalShared = newValue
        }
    }
    
}
```

And it seems the codes are ok, but I have issue to make use of it, the normal coding for super class would be:

```
let nsApplication: NSApplication = NSApplication.shared
```

And if want make use of MySubNSApplication, that would be this below codes in a main file:

```
import Cocoa

let myNSApplication: MySubNSApplication = MySubNSApplication.shared
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
myNSApplication.delegate = appDelegate
myNSApplication.run()
```

Which the error happens on line of `myNSApplication.run()`:

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

How can I solve this error?

---

update:

```
import Cocoa

let myNSApplication = NSApplication.shared as? MySubNSApplication
let appDelegate: AppDelegate = AppDelegate()
myNSApplication?.delegate = appDelegate
myNSApplication?.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

The application class used by the app in a new Xcode project is loaded from the `Info.plist` file. You can set a different class by going to your target settings, the Info tab, and replacing the value for `Principal class`.

By default it should be `NSApplication`, and when using Swift you should make sure to set the module/target as a prefix.

[image: Example]

Keep in mind that `NSApplication.shared` will still be annotated as `NSApplication`, so you'll have to cast it to your own class:

`let application = NSApplication.shared as? MyApplicationClass`

Comment: I took all steps but still not working, I used this string for `Principal class` -> `CustomNSApplication.MySubNSApplication` and it does not works, I update the codes I used at the end.